# How to find the normal boiling temperature if vapor pressure at any temperature is the only thing that can be usable?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, boiling-point

Here is my program for calculating the vapor pressure of the Organic Chemicals using Antoine's Equation:

```
def Psat_Antoine(temp,A,B,C):
    return numpy.exp(A-B/(temp+C))

A_Actn, B_Actn, C_Actn = 14.31451662590449, 2756.0411263712826, 228.03915724014055
A_Mthnl, B_Mthnl, C_Mthnl = 16.572099163421438, 3634.3383035408656, 239.33433646852495

temp = input("Give temperature in C:")
vapor_pressure_actn = Psat_Antoine(temp, A_Actn, B_Actn, C_Actn)
vapor_pressure_mthnl = Psat_Antoine(temp, A_Mthnl, B_Mthnl, C_Mthnl)
```

I want to calculate the normal boiling temperature of the Acetone, Methanol, or any kind of chemical that I know A, B, C constants. But there is a challenge, I can't use if, while or for loop. I have to use some kind of equation that calculates the normal boiling temperature of Acetone, Methanol etc. And the Psat_Antoine() function is the only thing that I can use to figure out the normal boiling temperature. Is it possible to write such program?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. The Antoine eqn. is $T=\frac{B}{A-\log_{10}p}-C$. So you just substitute in the values for A, B, and C, and the std. pressure in whatever units correspond to your constants (e.g., 760 mm Hg), and solve for T. This can be easily done in any computer algebra system, e.g., Mathematica, Maple, or Matlab, without needing *if*, *while* or *for*. If there's an additional requirement (which you didn't specify) that you must use Python, that's a programming question rather than a chemistry question, and thus should instead be posted on an appropriate programming site.

Comment: @theorist Why bother with computer algebra systems? The equation can easily be reversed by hand. Moreover, you already did that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  The OP's question isn't clealry written, so when he wrote "the Psat_Antoine() function is the only thing that I can use", I took that to mean "the Antoine equation is the only thing I can use."  So I provided it in terms of T, at which point it becomes trivially easy to create code that spits out bp given A, B, and C for various solvents without using *if*, *and*, or *for* using a CAS.   Yes, it can be done by hand, but the OP didn't want to know how to do this by hand, he wanted to know how to do this with code.  And the easiest way to do this with code is with a CAS....

Comment: ...it's the best tool for the job.  Now if what the OP instead meant is that he had to start with the Antoine eqn in terms of p, and use code to reverse it, my answer is still the same: use a CAS, since that's still clearly the best tool for the job, because it has built-in functions that do just that (reversing the eqn adds only one more line of code in a CAS).  OTOH, if the OP's requirement is that it specifically has to be done in Python, then he should have said that explicitly.  But his title doesn't say Python, it say he needs to do it using p and the constants.